# ввод и вывод float аргументов через Main

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с интересным и не совсем понятным поведением компилятора.

Вот фрагмент кода:

```
static float Main(float[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Неверное количество аргументов");
            return 0f;
        }
        else
        {
            float _catA, _catB, _hypoC;
            try
            {
                DefinitionOfParties(args, out _catA, out _catB, out _hypoC);

                if (IsValidTriangle(_catA, _catB, _hypoC))
                {
                    return AreaCalculation(_catA, _catB);
                }
                return 0f;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return 0f;
            }
        }
    }
```

Через окно дебага пытаюсь добавить три числа, но получаю ошибку при запуске:

> program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Непонятно чего от меня хочет VS?
Ругается на отсутствие точки входа, которая есть?

Comment: А куда и кому вы это значение вернуть хотите и кто должен параметры в Main передать такие?

Comment: @Андрей Вообще в задании описано что это будет подключаемая библиотека, но я не знаю как работать с такими вещами

Comment: Кажется я только что ответил на свой вопрос. Спасибо за наводку

Comment: Логично, библиотека не должна иметь точки входа, поэтому тип проекта соответствующий выберите и студия не будет требовать точку входа. Ну и заодно имя нормальное функции своей дайте.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потомучто *CLR* не может найти точку входа. При выполнении программы, написанной на C#, *CLR* ищет статический метод **Main** (но библиотеки и службы не требуют использования метода **Main** в качестве точки входа), помеченный IL(Intermediate Language) директивой `.entrypoint`, который принимает либо никаких аргументов, либо один аргумент  типа `string[]`, и имеет тип возврата `void` или `int`. Таким образом, подходят такие сигнатуры:

```
static void Main();
static void Main(string[] args);
static int Main();
static int Main(string[] args);
```